# how to propose when editing content 2 possible media style for an image field?

Tags: 8, media

My content type has an image field.
I'd like to propose to the editor two possible displays for that uploaded image, either 100% width or 50% width
How can i achieve that?

EDIT:
i found out this module :
https://www.drupal.org/project/field_image_style
Is this module stable enough?

How can I make this behavior compatible with the field formatter from colorbox module?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a separate select dropdown textfield with two options, which are the image styles you'd like, and if they select the alternate one, update the field in hook_entity_view.

```
 function mymodule_entity_view(array &$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
   if ($entity->getEntityType()->id() == 'node' && $entity->bundle() == 'article' && !$entity->field_image_style->isEmpty()) {
     $style = $entity->field_image_style->getValue()[0]['value'];
     $build['field_image'][0]['#image_style'] = $style;
   }
 }
```

Comment: mymodule_entity_view is not fired in my case when loading /node/nid !?

Comment: it definitely fires on node pages.  Try clearing cache, or to develop without the render cache on, put this in settings.php:   $settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null';

Comment: it is fired when function mymodule_entity_view(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {. is that because the copy paste makes the ide not adding the necessary use ... line?

Comment: I think it may be due to render caching.  Do you have render cache turned off?

Comment: $settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null'; generate an error. i enter the hook function if i write as my comment above. The style is not applied though, is it the machine name to assign in $style?